# How to repeat the rows based on value

Tags: oracle11g, oracle10g

The second column value wise return the row

Ex:

---

```
col_1     col_2
================
A          1
B          3
C          2
```

Result is:

---

```
col_1      col_2
================
A           1
B           3
B           3
B           3
C           2
C           2
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use this query.

```
WITH yourtable (col_1, col_2)
     AS (SELECT 'A', 1 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'A', 3 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'C', 2 FROM DUAL)
--The data above is for test purpose only
  SELECT col_1, col_2
    FROM yourtable
         CROSS JOIN (    SELECT ROWNUM n
                           FROM DUAL
                     CONNECT BY LEVEL <= (SELECT MAX (col_2) FROM yourtable))
   WHERE n <= col_2
ORDER BY col_1;
```

[**DEMO**](http://rextester.com/live/WOYVX20096)

Answer (score 0):

Yet another option:

```
SQL> with yourtable (col_1, col_2) as
  2    (select 'A', 1 from dual union all
  3     select 'B', 3 from dual union all
  4     select 'C', 2 from dual
  5    )
  6  select col_1, col_2
  7  from yourtable,
  8       table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
  9                           connect by level <= col_2)
 10                  as sys.odcinumberlist))
 11  order by col_1;

C      COL_2
- ----------
A          1
B          3
B          3
B          3
C          2
C          2

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```